# Laravel 4: Why does my class autoload but global variables are not available

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've autoloaded a class, which is properly namespaced and PSR-0. I put it in app/lib/CI, and the class and it's filename are the same "DB". The class file itself includes a config file before the actual class:

```
require( 'config.php' );

class DB {
  // ...
}
```

The class is clearly autoloading, because when I call the static method connect it does display an error message from inside ::connect(). The problem is, global variables that are inside the included config.php are not available inside the class::method.

So, to be clear, the array $connection_settings is inside config.php, but even when using:

```
global $connection_settings;
```

$connection_settings is not set inside the connect method.

Something interesting is that even though the class is autoloaded, if I include the class from the top of my routes.php file, everything works normally. So what am I not doing right to get autoloading to work the way I consider "normal"?

Comment: Won't this make stuff messy?

Comment: Whether or not is would make stuff messy is not the question. The fact is, I'd prefer to use alternate DB class, but when it is autoloaded, the global variable is not available inside the class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an issue with [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) rather than Laravel.  Composer makes every effort not to pollute the global scope during autoloading (discussed briefly in [#1297](https://github.com/composer/composer/pull/1297)).  If you want to force global variables then you should declare them as global in your config file, as well as in any function using them.

The [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) says:

> Using global keyword outside a function is not an error. It can be used if the file is included from inside a function.

The below code works for me (with Laravel 4b4 on PHP 5.4.13).  Removing either global line breaks the code (in different ways).

#### config.php

```
global $connection_settings;
$connection_settings = array(/* ... */);
```

#### DB.php

```
require 'config.php';
class DB {
    static function connect()
    {
        global $connection_settings;
        // Do something with $connection_settings
    }
}
```

Comment: This just fixed a problem I was having, but I have no idea why. Since `config.php` is included outside of the DB class, why is not part of the global scope? I'm autoloading my classes, but I'm not using Composer, so it can't be a Composer-specific issue.

Comment: @Nathanael , see my answer, I've made an attempt to explain exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

This has *nothing* to do with either Laravel *or* Composer, but rather with **autoload mechanics**. [Phill Sparks' great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15883356/624066) already pointed out a subtle yet crucial difference of including files using autoload, and that's the key to understand and solve your problem:

The [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) says:

> Using global keyword outside a function is not an error. It can be used if the file is included from inside a function.

When you use autoload via `spl_autoload_register()`, the `include` happens *inside* the autoloader function. So any variables declared in the included file body does **not** have global scope, the same for your `config.php` vars.

So, while you can access such vars in `DB.php` body, they are not available *inside* its classes and functions. That's why using `global` just inside `connect()` does not work: because such vars are not really global in the first place!

So you need to "make" them global *first*, by using `global` in the same scope where they were declared (either at `DB.php` or `config.php`) and *then* use `global` *again* inside `connect()` to access such vars.

A simple example:

**`test.php`:**

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require(__DIR__.'/'.$class.'.php');
});

$foo = new Foo();
var_dump($foo->bar());
```

**`Foo.php`:**

```
<?php

global $foobar;
$foobar = "just a test";

class Foo
{
    function bar() {
        global $foobar;
        return $foobar;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly and prints `just a test`. The first `global` *puts* `$foobar` at global scope, the second one *access* it. Removing *either* will break the code, the first omission being more "evil", as it will print `NULL` with no errors.

Comment: Brilliant answer, MestreLion. I was having the same problem accessing a global variable from within a Laravel class method. I kept getting null. Putting the keyword "global" in the variable declaration solved it. Thanks a lot! 

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems that the file is included from within a PHP function so all defined variables are scoped to that function. You need to take them and reassign them to global scope...

Something like

```php
  require_once 'file.php';
  foreach ( get_defined_vars() as $k => $v) {
    $GLOBALS[$k] = $v;
  }
```